# iptables guest network isolation not working

Tags: networking, iptables, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi setup as a router to serve a guest network.

Setup as follows:

- Pi interface eth0 connected to local home network (192.168.10.0/24)

  - through this network the Pi can connect to the internet
- Pi interface eth1 connected to local guest network

  - this uses a usb to rj45 adapter
  - Pi serves as DHCP on this network (192.168.20.0/24)

The Switch the Pi is connected to has a few ports assigned into a VLAN so they are separate from my home network.

So everything working fine until this point.

Next Step: Grant the guest network internet Access

Via the following commands I got that done:

```
# Enable Forwarding
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
   # Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4:
   net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Allow NAT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

So now my guest network has internet access but can also access my local home network.

I need some help with iptables rules to restrict access.

I would like to get the following working:

- Guest isolation

  - No member on the guest network can see/connect/ping with any other member on that network
- Members of the guest network are not allowed to access my home network
- Members of my home network are not allowed to see/connect/ping any member on the guest network

  - I got that one figured out I think? (correct me if I'm wrong please)

This is my iptables configuration so far:

```
# Restrict Access to Interface eth0 (local home network)
# Drop all traffic from RFC 1918 subnets
# Allow SSH and Ping from local home network to Pi's
# interface on the local home network for remote administration

sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/16 -i eth0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -i eth0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 172.16.0.0/12 -i eth0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 224.0.0.0/4 -i eth0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 240.0.0.0/5 -i eth0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -i eth0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
```

So in theory I cannot connect to anything in the guest network from my local network except for ping and SSH right?

How do I turn this around so my guest network computers cannot connect to anything in my local home network but still access the internet?
In my testing I either restrict everything (even internet) or I can still access networkshares for example.

regards
Alkahna

Answer (score 0):

After some more try and error I came up with this set of commands/rules

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.0.0/16 -i eth1 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -d 10.0.0.0/8 -i eth1 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -d 172.16.0.0/12 -i eth1 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -d 224.0.0.0/4 -i eth1 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -d 240.0.0.0/5 -i eth1 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -d 127.0.0.0/8 -i eth1 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -d 127.0.0.0/8 -i eth1 -j DROP
```

basically dropping everything coming into eth1 (my guest network) that has a RFC 1918 subnet as the destination.

With those rules I cannot ping my home network.

Somehow I can ping the Pi's second NIC that is in my home network though, should that be the case or does this raise any concerns?

But I'm still lost on guest isolation.